# YouTubeのようなサイト（またはアプリ）を開発する場合、サーバ側の要求スペックの考え方を教えてください。

Tags: サーバー管理

いつもお世話になっております。
曖昧な表現が含まれるかもしれません。何かあればご指摘ください。

YouTubeのような会員がアップロードしたデータを会員・非会員が視聴するシステムのウェブサイト（またはアプリ）を作る場合、会員規模やデータサイズによると思うのですが、どのようなスペックのサーバが望まれるでしょうか。

前提条件として下記のYouTubeとの差があります。
・動画ファイルではなく、音声ファイルのみを扱う。ただしASMRのような容量が大きい場合がある
・音声のみの生放送を可能にしたい（YouTubeやニコニコ、ツイキャスのようなリアルタイムコメント機能も並行して動作させたい。

音声放送なのでラジオ放送のイメージに近いと思います。
サーバサイドが私の専門外なのでざっくりな内容で十分です。
タグのジャンルが想像つかなかったのですみませんが不備ございましたらご指摘ください。

Comment: 同時接続数、音声データの数等によりかなり変わってくると思いますので、一概には言えないと思います。同時接続数が少なく、音声データの数も少なければ、市販のパソコン程度でも可能かと思いますが、多ければ大規模サーバーになると思います。

Comment: ディスク容量以外にも CPU やメモリのスペック等も考慮する必要があるので、一概に答えを出すのは難しいと思います。

Comment: 池田茂樹様　 cubick様　ご指摘ありがとうございます。まだ漠然とした概念の段階で私もサーバに詳しくないのでどのような規模をどの段階で導入していくのかマイルストーンもありません。導入直後はともかく、最終的に万単位・それ以上のアカウントが現れ、24時間常に誰かが利用してくるような状態を現在想定しております。これはサーバ運営会社にどのようなプランがあってどのような運用実績があるか聞いてみたほうが早そうでしょうか。

Comment: 例えば「配信サーバ スペック」と検索すると配信向けのレンタルサーバーなども見つかります、まずはそれらのスペックを参考にしてはどうでしょか？もっとも、レンタル等なんらかのサービスを利用するような場合、転送量の方が重要になってきそうです。

Comment: キーワードありがとうございます。その手のワードを調べてみます。

Comment: @cubick この質問がモデレーター権限でクローズされた理由は何ですか？
どのような編集が行なわれると再オープンされますか？

Comment: 「この質問は 主観性の高い質問 です。この質問では現在、回答を受け付けていません。」との理由でクローズ状態になっているようです。自分は解決策をいただけたのでこのままクローズ扱いで大丈夫ですが…。